# Problems with images in html

Tags: html, web-development-server

I’m completly beginer in a web development. Currently, I’m learning a basic stuff but I have a huge issue with a procces of adding pictures in code.

I watched many tutorials on youtube and I try basicaly everything
(img src=NAME OF THE PICTURE + jpg/png)
(img src=URL LING FROM THE GOOGLE)
and many other things but unfortuntely I didn’t found proper solution.
I will be realy greatfull if there’s someone who can give me a good advice so I can solve my issue

P.S sorry if I made some gramar mistakes, I’m not native English speaker

Thanks

```
type here
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

to add image you can do :

```html
<img src="https://nothingelse.fr/img/new_logo_ne.png" />
```

And you can visit : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility you are accidentally copying image's website instead of image adress,if this is the problem when you are searching for an image after you right click make sure you are selecting "copy image adress"

End result can be something like this

```
     <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/tZLxhLAWoEFRpf0pe-CirjvF0XY=/1400x788/filters:format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/15788040/20150428-cloud-computing.0.1489222360.jpg" />
```

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem and now I solved it, thank You veary much

Answer (score 0):

To add a image you use this code and you put the image path but make sure you get a right    if you are using image from internet use copy image adress not link adress